# Deleting hyperlinks performance

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I want to delete all hyperlinks on currently active sheet via VBA.

For that I am using `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete` command, which works fine and does not take virtually any time...

All that **until I have opened two workbooks containing hyperlinks** at the same time. In that case, the very **same command takes much more time** (minutes) to finish. It does its job, removing hyperlinks from the activesheet only, but in longer time. It seems somehow the other worksheets with hyperlinks is slowing it down.

I can have multiple workbooks opened at the same time, but they must not have any hyperlinks for the macro to work fast.

Can someone help me to overcome this?

I actually am in a situation where I frequently need to have both hyperlinks workbooks opened at the same time and running the macro which deletes hyperlinks.

Comment: If I attempt to reproduce this behavior it would help to know the version of Excel and if you have changed any of the options (Alt+F, T) regarding Hyperlinks or Proofing ► AutoCorrect ► AutoFormat.

Comment: Excel version is 2010 Standard and I am not aware of any changes made to hyperlinks or autoformat settings. However, there are many other macros in those sheets. But I've tried debugging and all other commands work fine, except for thjis exact one that gets stuck for minutes before continuing, so I believe the other macros are probably not hampering it.

Comment: I played around with my own options a bit but the longest it took me to delete 7500 hyperlinks on the ActiveSheet (with two workbooks full of hyperlinks open) was 00:00:00.426, Check it with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`; maybe even `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Remember to turn everything back on.

Comment: Well, I've forgotten to disable calculations and ScreenUpdating, but it didn't make any difference. But i've spotted, that the slower Excel has hyperlinks added programatically via VBA (Hyperlinks.Add), when the other one has them using hyperlink function formula. I'll try in the future to change the slower one to also uswe formulas instead of VBA, but currently I can't and still would like to find out where's the bug...

Comment: it may sound silly but try adding    `activeworkbook.activesheet.hyperlinks.delete ` for more direct reffernace

Comment: How are you adding the hyperlinks? Inserting a hyperlink object acts differently than a hyperlink formula does.

Comment: What does your formula look like? I used a formula `=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!B2",M1)` on 40,000 rows then used `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete` and nothing happened. When I inserted a Hyperlink into those 40,000 rows, the code worked basically instantly.

Comment: Use exact address. like thisworkbook.sheets(1).hyperlinks.delete or for each sheet in thisworkbook.sheets sheet.hyperlinks.delete I usualy avoid using active in any reference. causes more trouble than merit

Comment: I am not using HYPERLINK formula, but adding them from VBA via `Hyperlinks.Add`, but none of the suggestions have worked so far. :(

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but I'd consider starting your code with a check to see if other workbooks are open in the instance and if they are save the activeworkbook, open an new instance of excel and reopen the workbook in the new instance. Then run your code again.

Something like this to open the new instance:

```
Sub BlahBlah
if morethan1 then
    CWb = ActiveWorkbook.name
    ActiveWorkbook.save
    Dim objXL
    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXL.Visible = True
    application.displayalerts = false
        objXL.Workbooks.Open = CWb
    application.displayalerts = True
end if
End Sub
```

If you isolate the workbook you should return to your normal runtime